# Update previously patched package with Yarn Berry

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

I'm using Yarn@3.0.2 in my project.

I have patched a package (@pkg/pkg) with the command `yarn patch @pkg/pkg` and I am using it as a devDependency with the `patch:` protocol.

Now I need to make another patch to the same package - but when I run the same command I get `Multiple candidate packages found [...]`.

It works when trying to target the original package (using `yarn patch @pkg/pkg@x.x.x)`, but I can't seem to find a way to target the patched project.

Any skilled yarn developer out there?

(Possibly useful information: I cannot use the `resolutions` field for the patch since @pkg/pkg is a CLI which does not seem to work with this approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was choose the patch suggested with the error and encapsule it in qoutes such as:

`yarn patch "patch:..."`

Comment: I am getting "No package found in the project for the given locator". Just copied patch string from resolutions in package.json...

Comment: I originally ran into the same `Usage Error: No package found in the project for the given locator` error, but realized I need to include the package name and entire string, up to and including the trailing period that showed up for mine, like `yarn patch "foo@patch:foo@npm%3A11.1.0#./.yarn/patches/foo-npm-11.1.0-044300d42a.patch::version=11.1.0&hash=9322f9&locator=frontend%40workspace%3A."`